# How to keep broadcast recevier alive even after restarting the phone?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I am trying to make an app in which i am using broadcast receiver. My requirement is to keep my broadcast receiver alive when i install my application in the phone and exiting out after running it. I am able to get it up to this requirement,but when I am killing the application with the use of Task manager, broadcast receiver is not triggering, and I also want to keep my broadcast receiver alive even somebody restarting the phone.here is my code for main activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)     getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        PhoneStateListener psl = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    Intent intent2open = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    intent2open.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                    intent2open.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                    intent2open.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent2open.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent2open.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    intent2open.setFlags(0);

        Toast.make_Text(Context(),
            "Incoming call" + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTHLONG)
                            .show();
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };
        telephony Manager.listen(psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    }
```

**Below is my broadcast receiver code:**

```
@Override
    public void on Receive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method stub

        String state = intent.get String Extra(Telephony Manager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);

        if(state.equals(Telephony Manager.CALL_STATE_RINGING))
        {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.example.app.Activity");
            intent2.putExtras(intent2);
            intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent2);

        }

    }
```

Below is my manifest.xml code:

```
    <application

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.app.Receiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.app.Activity" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Please help me!!!..... Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a service and register the broadcast receiver in that service.
You should start the service using startService so that it runs always.
For running it after reboot create a broadcast receiver which will registered for booting complete action and this will start the ^service.